# Python - Python loop that writes files from requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, loops, python-requests

I am trying to write a loop that gets .json from an url via requests, then writes the .json to a .csv file. Then I need it to it over and over again until my list of names (.txt file) is finished(89 lines). I can't get it to go over the list, it just picks the bottom name of my list and then quits. I need it to go through and basically create 89 files, with the corrects urls. The other functions works properly, but it only does it once.

I can't seem to find a loop fitting for my purpose. Since I am a total beginner of python I hope I can get some help here and learn more.

## My code so far.

```py
#Opens the file with pricelists

with open('prislistor.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        pricelists = (line.strip())
     
response = requests.get('https://api.example.com/3/prices/sublist/{}/'.format(pricelists), headers=headers)

#Formats it
parsed = json.loads(response.text)

listan=(json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

#Converts and creates a .csv file.
data = parsed['Prices']

with open('listan-{}.csv'.format(pricelists), 'w') as outf:
    dw = csv.DictWriter(outf, data[0].keys())
    dw.writeheader()
    
    for row in data:
        dw.writerow(row)

print ("The file list-{}.csv is created!".format(pricelists))
```

Comment: instead of pricelists = (line.strip()), do you mean to append to pricelists? e.g. pricelists.append(line.strip())

Comment: Tried it and but still wont write out all the data to individual files.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are only getting data from one of your responses. You probably want to keep track of them all. You can do that by appending each response to a list, parsing each one individually, and then adding it's data to your output. Something like this:

```
#Opens the file with pricelists

pricelists = []

with open('prislistor.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        pricelists.append(line.strip())

# build responses 
responses = [] 
for pricelist in pricelists: 
    response.append(requests.get('https://api.example.com/3/prices/sublist/{}/'.format(pricelist), headers=headers))

#Format each response 
fullData = [] 
for response in responses: 
    parsed = json.loads(response.text)
    listan=(json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

    #Converts and creates a .csv file.
    fullData.append(parsed['Prices'])



with open('listan-{}.csv'.format(pricelists), 'w') as outf:
    dw.writeheader()
    for data in fullData: 
        dw = csv.DictWriter(outf, data[0].keys())

        for row in data:
            dw.writerow(row)

print ("The file list-{}.csv is created!".format(pricelists))
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! I tried out the code but got the following name error. ´´´NameError: name 'response' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I solved the first error I posted in the comments by import response, but now I am getting this error.

`AttributeError: module 'response' has no attribute 'append'`

Do I need to import more libraries?

Edit: Changed 'response' to 'responses' which seems more right since 'response' has not been defined i believe. But after I changed it I got another error:

`with open('listan-{}.csv'.format(pricelists), 'w') as outf:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "listan-['A..`

Is this an os bug because I am using windows 10, should I switch to a linux distro?